# Centering Shapes/Objects in SFML for C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, sfml

So recently, I have begun using SFML to make games in Visual Studio.
After setting everything up, and writing some sample code, I devised this:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 600), "Move the Shape");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program produces the following result:
[image: Move the Shape UNCENTERED]

How do I place the circle in the center? I want to set up some code after that lets the user move the circle with the keyboard's arrow keys, so I need the circle in the center.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the position of `shape` with [`shape.setPosition(x, y)`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Transformable.php#a4dbfb1a7c80688b0b4c477d706550208). You know the width and height of the window (600px each way), and you know the radius of the circle (100px), so you can calculate the x and y that the circle needs to be moved to be centered. I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

You may also want to consider setting the origin of your circle so that you can position it by its center point (see [`setOrigin`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Transformable.php#a56c67bd80aae8418d13fb96c034d25ec)).

Comment: I just found that out myself, but thanks for telling me about the `setOrigin` part.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've answered my own question. To set the position of an item, write:

```
shape.setPosition(x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center a circle you can do something like this

```
circle.setPosition((window.getSize().x / 2.f) - circle.getRadius(), (window.getSize().y / 2.f) - circle.getRadius());
```

Comment: what about a rectangle shape?

Answer (score -1):

First, you should set the origin of the circle in the middle of it:

`circle.setOrigin( circle.getRadius() / 2 , circle.getRadius() / 2 );`

The, just move the center of the circle in the middle of the scree:

```
circle.setPosition( window.getSize().x / 2 , window.getSize().y / 2 );
```

Comment: I don't think you would want to divide the radius by two (were you thinking diameter?)